# Best PHP thumbnailer/resizer class?

Tags: php, image-manipulation

What is the nest PHP thumbnailer/resizer class that preferably works on most shared hosts?

Clarification: I'm looking for a PHP class/wrapper (eg. [phpThumb()](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/), [Asido](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asido)), so I don't have to run [GD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library) or [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) functions directly. I'm specifically looking for resizing and framing functions.

Comment: Why use a wrapper when the original tools are more powerful?

Comment: it's much simpler than using the GD image functions directly

Comment: If you want to stick within that wrapper's intended use cases, sure.  If you want to do something they didn't anticipate, though, you'll be SOL and have to delve into the inner workings of GD again. Learn the underlying functions once and you'll be in better shape.

Answer (score 4):

I have good experiences with both [phpThumb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpthumb/) and [Wideimage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wideimage/). Wideimage is the more modern PHP5 approach while phpThumb has much more features.

Comment: thanks! it's the first time i heard of wideimage ;) i'll check it out

Comment: btw i've had some problems when I use phpThumb on some shared hosts

Comment: what's more modern about Wideimage?

Answer (score 1):

[Asido](http://asido.info) works great with [some modifications](http://singletonio.blogspot.com/2008/09/asido-php-thumbnailer-resizer-class.html) ;)
It supports most features that I need (resizing, framing), has drivers for both GD and Imagemagick, nice simple API, and organized codebase.

Answer (score 0):

GD is supported on many hosts
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best two (and by far the most common) are either GD or ImageMagick. I've had a lot of joy with the second.

Answer (score 0):

Imagick is a native PHP extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API. It is used on many shared hosts:

http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick is good, and has two APIs for PHP:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#php

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#php

Answer (score 0):

I've found that both ImageMagick and GD are too slow for creating un-cacheable dynamic images on the fly if you have more than one request per second. I had to serve dozens of requests per second, and found that I could get around 50 times speed improvement by writing the routine as FastCGI with C & jpeglib.

Comment: not the answer that i'm looking for, but certainly good information! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Greg_Photo](http://www.gregphoto.net/index.php/2007/02/03/announcing-gregphoto_image-a-php5gd2-thumbnail-class/) as an accessor to the underlying GD commands. For pretty basic resizing it works great.

Comment: Dude, your link just crashed my chrome (malware alert).

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick will definitely produce really sharp images, but it's not easy to install or manage.  ImageMagick itself needs to be installed on the server, and then a compatinble version of MagickWand needs to be installed.

I've also found that it has a habit of creating massive temporary files of up to a GB or more and then dumping them into your /tmp directory, which you need to be careful of.  It will also eat up a massive amount of memory unpredictably.

For these reasons, I would not recommend ImageMagick if you are on a shared host.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great script with great documentation. http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/